# Blender sculpt symmetry is asymmetric! [issue]

Tags: sculpting, mirror, sculpt

Symmetry is not working in sculpt mode: when I point the brush to a random polygon, you can see one of the blue dots is outside the mesh, like the symmetry axis is offset. You can see the issue in the image below... thanks a lot for your help! [image: symmetry issue]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, symmetry will use the origin of the object as the center, is it correctly placed?

Comment: I center the pivot point but the same issue is occurring again (added an image on the initial post)

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/78386c998ab542adbf57f832ffbf1931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the local orientation to check the origin's orientation:

[image]

As you see it is tilted, i.e. not aligned with the global orientation, so the symmetry won't happen as you expect, you need to apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: How come mine isn't? https://ibb.co/vQfLX3g

Comment: BTW ok now it works! Thanks a lot

Comment: you need to display the local orientation, in your image you display the global orientation